# Get the latest build of Windows in S Mode

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I just purchased a Microsoft Surface Go. It comes in "S-Mode" which means I can't install anything on it without going through the Microsoft Store. Now I am trying to install a software and I can't because it requires Windows 10 version 18362.0 or higher and I am in version 17763.914. I ran Windows Update twice and restarted the device but it didn't upgraded the Windows build number.

Are there any way to upgrade to the latest build of Windows in S Mode or am I stuck to wait and hope Microsoft pushes me an update one day ?

Comment: Is there a reason you don’t deactivate S Mode?  Takes less than 30 seconds.

Comment: Because it can't be undone, I wanted to try it for a few days before deciding if I switch or not.

Comment: I am 99% sure, it is intentional not possible, to install a feature update while the device is in S Mode.  S Mode images are highly customizable, the feature update images distributed over Windows Update, are not compatible with S Mode.  However, I have no source for that information l, other than know S Mode images are highly customized for the device.  I don’t particularly agree with the duplicate vote in a case like this.

Comment: Does Microsoft Charge to Leave S Mode?

Leaving S Mode is free. Before Windows 10 in S Mode, there was Windows 10 S. Microsoft planned to charge $50 to switch from Windows 10 S to a standard desktop edition of Windows 10.

However, Microsoft relented on these plans, and Windows 10 S is gone. With Windows 10 in S Mode, leaving this mode is free.  
How to Leave S Mode (https://www.howtogeek.com/360007/how-to-leave-windows-10s-s-mode/)